# WPF RichTextBox bullet

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm binding to Error property, which `Error = sb.ToString()`, where `sb` is a `stringbuilder` type. I'm used `FlowDocument` and Paragraph in `xaml`.

How can I create **multi bullets** for `sb`?

.

Comment: replace newlines with newlines+bullet

Answer (score 0):

You should return an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a single string, having a single string for each item before the bullet point. Then bind to an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 5 5 0" Width="20" Text="•" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 5 0 0" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```